# Mandar valores para un RangeValues ​en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito que cuando el slider aparezca tenga sus valores de inicio y fin justo en sus valores min y max. Me explico mejor, digamos que necesito que el slider vaya desde 100 hasta 500, esos serian mis valores para min y max del RangeSlider. Ahora el campo de valores quiero que al iniciar tengan esos mismos valores para que el control deslizante este completamente abierto de extremo a extremo los valores de mínimo y máximo pueden variar según una búsqueda y por eso tengo que mandar los parametros.

En otro Widget aparte obtengo los valores que necesito entonces mando a llamar a mi Widget donde esta el slider algo asi:

```
ContenidoCardFiltros(min: snapshot.data!.precioMenor,max: snapshot.data!.precioMayor)
```

en mi Widget con el slider recibo los dos parametros (que son double):

```
class ContenidoCardFiltros extends StatefulWidget {
  final double min, max;
  const ContenidoCardFiltros({Key? key, required this.min,required this.max}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContenidoCardFiltrosState createState() => _ContenidoCardFiltrosState();
}

class _ContenidoCardFiltrosState extends State<ContenidoCardFiltros> {

  RangeValues rangos = new RangeValues(300,500);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
            RangeSlider(
                values: rangos,
                min: widget.min,
                max: widget.max,
                onChanged: (RangeValues values){
                  setState(() {
                    print (values);

                    rangos = values;
                  });
                },
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

eso me crea un slider que se ve algo asi: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el slider funciona como debería, pero necesito que en vez de elegir manualmente unos valores como ese RangeValues ​​(300,500), que tenga los valores del min y max para que se vea asi: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que esta línea: RangeValues ​​rangos = new RangeValues ​​(300,500); tiene que estar fuera del:

@override Widget build (contexto BuildContext) {.....

teniendo esa línea afuera del build el slider se comporta bien, si yo muevo el slider se ve visualmente que se mueve, pero como esta fuera del build no puedo asignarle el valor que tiene min y max (widget.min, widget.max)

si coloco esa linea dentro del buil entonces ya puedo acceder ese widget.min pero el slider deja de comportarse como debe, aunque yo arrastre el slider, no se moverá, aunque si en consola imprimo los valores me dice que si se esta moviendo

en resumen necesito que una vez de tener valores por defecto: RangeValues ​​rangos = new RangeValues ​​(300,500);

pueda iniciar esos valores en el min y max del RangeSlider: RangeValues ​​rangos = new RangeValues ​​(widget.min, widget.max);

pero que siga moviendose el slider.

Que debería hacer?

Comment: Lo logre! 
lo que hice fue llamar a 
@override
initState(){
} 
y dentro de las llaves si se puede mandar a llamar a widget.min, este initState lo pongo justo abajo de la linea donde tenia el problema (arriba de RangeValues) y el init hace algo muy parecido a sobrescribir lo anterior.

Comment: justo voy a hacer un video sobre el ciclo de vida de los widgets, esta semana sale, sigue mi canal : diegoveloper  (youtube)